# How to add my WFS data to ArcGIS operations dashboard?

Tags: arcgis-online, wfs, web-mapping, operations-dashboard

I'm trying to build an operations dashboard in ArcGIS Online.
After adding my WFS layer to a web map I had to add some custom parameters to actually show the real-time data (points and metadata). When I added the map to my dashboard I wanted to add a chart, but the following notification came up:

> <The map doesn't contain layers that can be used>.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Parameters are srsNAME for dutch coördinate system and box to narrow down the amount of points.

Here's the WFS if it might help
https://waterwebservices.rijkswaterstaat.nl/services/distributielaagWFS/distributielaag_dbo?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=locatiesmetlaatstewaarneming&srsName=EPSG:28992&bbox=140000,400000,180000,430000,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:28992&Maxfeatures=50

Comment: Is the dashboard expecting any particular format from the data? Could it be that it can't use `text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1` which is the only format available for features for the service

Comment: Just as a note, you have `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:28992` in your URI which is incorrect the correct URN is: `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992`